# Two versions of Spring Framework in a single app?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am developing my app, using Spring v3. Now I have included another module (using Maven), which, in turn, depends on Spring v4. While my app and this module work perfectly fine, when booted separately, cooperation just fails.

Is it possible to combine my app with this module somehow, resulting in two different version of Spring bundled into resulting app?

Comment: It would be easier to upgrade your spring to version 4.

Comment: It's not. Because my "zoo" also relies on a component, which is build on top of Spring V3.

Comment: I see, so you would have to do some kind isolation of your app classloader, separating the libraries, I did that a while ago with jasper libraries I've made a handle wich identifies which version of jasper libs it would have to load. In the same app I had jasper 3.0.0, 3.7.6 and 4 because the app was huge and the client wouldn't pay the conversion

Comment: *Try* using Spring 4. It's nearly completely backwards compatible for client code.

Comment: @chrylis I am trying. But it's embedded in dependencies so deeply. Omg!)

Comment: @DenisKulagin did you find a solution? I am in a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

`OSGi` is one alternative to isolate you `classloader` and allow use different versions of the same library in one application. You can start learning it on [this article](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077837/java-se-hello-osgi-part-1-bundles-for-beginners.html).